# Player Staying On Moving Surface Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a 2d platformer game in unity and there's a part where there are moving platforms and I want them to fall off of them but they stay on them how could I make this?

[image: Player]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.